# Infinite Loop Working for One Part of the 2D Array

Tags: c, loops, microcontroller

The code I have works when I compile it in Xcode and run `printf` statements for the dash and dots for each letter. But when I put the code in the TI Code Composer Studio the code works but it only flashed a light on my microcontroller for the first letter "G" of "Go Knights".

I know it has something to do with the "while" loop but I'm not sure what it is. I've moved everything around, turned flashes on/off, turned my counter off, changed my variables from global to local variables, checked syntax for anything missing, removed the if statement for `==-1` and nothing has worked

```
#include <msp430g2553.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

unsigned int i = 0;
unsigned int j=0;
int row = 0;

void main(void)`
{

char str [] = "Go Knights";
int morse_array [36][6] = { //array for A-Z, 0-9 in morse code
    {0,1,-1},      //'.' = 0 and '-' = 1 and all else = -1
    {1,0,0,0,-1},
    {1,0,1,0,-1},
    {1,0,0,-1},
    {0,-1},
    {0,0,1,0,-1},
    {1,1,0,-1},
    {0,0,0,0,-1},
    {0,0,-1},
    {0,1,1,1,-1},
    {1,0,1,-1},
    {0,1,0,0,-1},
    {1,1,-1},
    {1,0,-1},
    {1,1,1,-1},
    {0,1,1,0,-1},
    {1,1,0,1,-1},
    {0,1,0,-1},
    {0,0,0,-1},
    {1,-1},
    {0,0,1,-1},
    {0,0,0,1,-1},
    {0,1,1,-1},
    {1,0,0,1,-1},
    {1,0,1,1,-1},
    {1,1,0,0,-1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,-1},
    {0,1,1,1,1,-1},
    {0,0,1,1,1,-1},
    {0,0,0,1,1,-1},
    {0,0,0,0,1,-1},
    {0,0,0,0,0,-1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,-1},
    {1,1,0,0,0,-1},
    {1,1,1,0,0,-1},
    {1,1,1,1,0,-1}
};


WDTCTL = WDTPW | WDTHOLD;    // stop watchdog timer
P1DIR |= 0x41;         //set the direction register for LED1 and LED2
P1OUT &= 0xBE;         //initialize LED1 and LED2 to off*/

for(;;){               //empty for loop is an infinite loop

    for (i=0; i<strlen(str); i++) {
        if(str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z'){
            row = (str[i]- 'a');
        }
        else if(str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z'){
            row = (str[i]- 'A');
        }
        else if(str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9'){
            row = (str[i] - '0');
        }
        else{
            row = -1;
        }

        j= 0;

        while(morse_array[row][j]!= -1){
            // DOT

            if(row == -1){
                for(i=0; i<140000; i++);
                break;
            }
            if(morse_array[row][j] == 0) {
                P1OUT ^= 0x40;
                for (i=0; i <25000; i++);
                P1OUT &= 0x00;
                for (i=0; i <30000;i++);
            }

            //Dash
            else if(morse_array[row][j] == 1) {
                P1OUT ^= 0x40;
                for (i=0; i<60000; i++);
                P1OUT &= 0x00;
                for (i=0; i<30000; i++);
            }

            j++;
        }
    }
    P1OUT ^= 0x01;
    for (i=0; i<30000; i++);
    P1OUT ^= 0x01;
```

}
}

Comment: 1) Watch your loop variables -- you are reusing them. 2) If row is -1 this line accesses out of bounds: `while(morse_array[row][j]!= -1)`. 3) You have a bug assigning the wrong value for row when input is a digit.

Comment: @MFisherKDX 1) I've updated my variables in my `while` loop and it loops through every letter now, but the only problem I'm running into is the program not recognizing the space between words. I've tried placing the `if (row == -1)` statement outside of the while loop (before and after), at the end of the while loop and have also tried to change the statement to `if(morse_array[row][j] == -1)`.I've also tried to create a `while (row == - 1)` loop outside after the first `while` loop but that does nothing. My thoughts are to have `row==-1` outside of the `while` loop but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

You have your first for-loop where you use variabele 'i'. In that for-loop, you have 2 for-loops that also use variable 'i'.
Looking at the j++, you should be using variable 'j' for the first for-loop.

Comment: you were right that I need to change the variable. I added a new global variable `unsigned int k = 0` and set `k=0` right before the while loop. This worked to help traverse the array